# How to save file to Android/Media on flutter

Tags: android, flutter

Been trying all day for the best way to create an app specific folder on anroid 11 devices.

I tried `/storage/0/emulated/Android/data/com.talkmia.app/files` from path_provider plugin as well as `/storage/0/emulated/Android/data/com.talkmia.app/` but app data gets cleared after uninstall and i think `android:hasFragileData` is useless because it'd only prompt if the app was uinstalled the normal way and it also keeps flutter's own extra data.

I did try SAF too with the `saf` packages but turns out you can't request access to root-storage and it doesn't make sense to ask users to create the folder then grant permission for that folder.

My only option now is to do it just like WhatsApp does it own. Create it in the `Android/Media` which i'm finding it hard to do. I've read a number of SO posts as well as Github Issues some suggesting MediaStore API while another suggested using the `Context::getExternalMediaDirs` which would create the app directory in the `Android/Media`.

Sighs! My Question now is how can get this `Context::getExternalMediaDirs` done in dart/flutter. I'd really like not to write platform code .

Answer (score 0):

**Using this package** : [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider/example)

**Step 1**: Get the commonly used file path

```
Future<String> getFilePath() async {
    Directory appDocumentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(); // 1
    String appDocumentsPath = appDocumentsDirectory.path; // 2
    String filePath = '$appDocumentsPath/demoTextFile.txt'; // 3

    return filePath;
  }
```

**Step 2**: Write content and save the file

```
void saveFile() async {
    File file = File(await getFilePath()); // 1
    file.writeAsString("demo file : demoTextFile.txt"); // 2
  }
```

**Step 3**: Read the file

```
void readFile() async {
    File file = File(await getFilePath()); // 1
    String fileContent = await file.readAsString(); // 2

    print('File Content: $fileContent');
}
```

Comment: Also see path_provider package example provide all directory actions

Comment: the `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();` returns `/data/0/com.talkmia.app/` as the directory and files stored there would be deleted when the app is uninstalled.

Comment: yes it will be deleted when you remove app, because this is stored in app (internal) memory.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't serve my purpose in any manner

Answer (score 0):

As I Know There no way until now to go Directly To Android/Media
But This Code Will Help You To Interact With Media Folder

package : path_provider

```
 late Future<String> _externalStorageDirectory;


Future<String> _getMediaStorageDirectory() async {
final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
String pathMedia = directory!.path.replaceFirst("data", "media");
pathMedia = pathMedia.replaceFirst("files", "");

return pathMedia;}
```

and Do't Forget To Initialize it

```
 @override
 void initState() {
 super.initState();
_externalStorageDirectory = _getMediaStorageDirectory();
 }
```